# Why does the third quarter regularly have the smallest number of samples for certain vector sizes?

Tags: r

Whenever I compute quartiles with the `quantile` function in R for a vector whose size is equal to certain odd numbers (every number with the tens and units slot being greater than or equal to 15), I always get the third quarter with the smallest number of elements.

Examples

```
 > t <- runif(n=15,min=1,max=19999)
 > t.s <- cut(t, breaks=quantile(t,probs=seq(0,1,by=0.25)), include.lowest=T)
 > summary(t.s)
 [983,5.27e+03] (5.27e+03,9.63e+03] (9.63e+03,1.46e+04] (1.46e+04,1.88e+04] 
              4                   4                   3                   4 

 > t <- sample.int(1000,111)
 > t.s <- cut(t, breaks=quantile(t,probs=seq(0,1,by=0.25)), include.lowest=T)
 > summary(t.s)
 [7,264] (264,575] (575,787] (787,999] 
   28        28        27        28
```

Is this a feature of R or something to do with number theory?

Comment: Which results in what I'm seeing... type 1 reproducibly gives the first quarter as having the lowest number. The math is beyond me but thanks. You can expand your comment in an answer and I'll mark 'solved'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 9 quantile algorithms to choose from. By default R uses type 7. Described in `?quantile`.  As noted if you choose other algorithms you will get other default behaviour.
The Algorithms used are also outlined in the `?quantile`